# What will happen if I don't use RS232 driver for UART?

Tags: uart, rs232

I already read some topics about the difference between UART and RS232, but I still didn't get it.

I read that UART is kind of logical interface, and RS232 is physical interface. But I don't understand that.

We usually use a RS232 driver for UART. Because the driver will make a link between the logical and the physical interface.
To really understand that, I'm asking what will happen if we don't use it.
Is this driver kind of buffer? So we need it?
What will this driver do?

(We will suppose we have the same level (3.3 V on both side)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The UART is the brain.

Your brain takes raw information received from sensory information from somewhere and converts it into something you understand and can react to. When you read this text you are decoding the alphabetic cypher information that are words and extracting meaning from it. A UART does a similar thing with the ones and zeros on a digital line.

We use many communication methods to transmit our human information over a distance. Things like this forum, the internet, or a telephone system.

Each communication method has their own standards they employ to convert the information from the sender into another form that can be sent over some distance and then converted back, hopefully error free, at the receiver end.

The RS232 standard is one of those standards. It defines how a signal is to be generated for transmission down a pair of wires and how that signal should be received at the other end. However, RS232 itself has no idea what the signal itself means.

Historically, RS323 and UART sort of got lumped into the same meaning since a Serial Port (which by the way has it's own standard over and above the rest) was predominantly a UART + RS232 for many decades. However, it is important to understand that the RS232 part is merely a signal specification. You can in fact send any digital signal via RS232 signal levels.

The UART outputs and receives simple digital signals. For short distances, inches to maybe a foot or so, you do not need to convert to RS232 or any other communication standard.

Like two people chatting in the same room, the range of your voice is usually fine. If you want to talk to your spouse at work on the other side of the city, you need a phone, or a computer.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing various distinct things.

**RS-232** is a standard for how to transmit digital data serially.  This standard specifies the voltage levels and polarities, among other things.  PC COM ports, for example, adhere to the RS-232 standard.

A **UART** is a digital circuit that does the conversion to and from the serial signaling.  A single UART usually handles both the received and transmitted signals.  The UART serial signals are usually normal digital logic levels, and are therefore not RS-232.  They are also usually inverted from RS-232.  Something commonly known as a "MAX 232" (after a popular Maxim part) is often used to convert between the logic-level serial signals of a UART and the voltage levels required by RS-232.  Such a chip also performs the *line driver* function (see below).

A **driver** is a piece of firmware or software that presents the hardware capabilities of a UART in more abstract form, usually as a procedural interface.  Drivers also handle the interface details of particular UARTs, and present a more hardware-independent interface to the rest of the software.

A **line driver** is a circuit that produces the right voltages at the right impedances to drive a signal, usually intended to go some distance.  In the case of RS-232, the aforementioned MAX 232 type of chips are often what is used as the line driver.

Comment: Well, at least in my region, people commonly call interface chips (such as MAX232) as a driver, which is, of course, not strictly correct, but people use it on everyday basis. I think the OP meant the same when was referring to driver.

Comment: "transmit digital data over a single signal" hmmm... not sure about the single part in there... It's at least a pair including ground. Driver also has different meanings, the software one really being a bit of a misnomer. Handler would have been better for that. +1 anyway though.

Comment: In the context of this question, "driver" apparently refers to a "line driver" (ie MC1488 Quadruple Line Driver, etc) and not a software peripheral driver

Comment: @Trevor: By saying "single signal", I was trying to contrast with a parallel interface.  I deliberately said "signal" as apposed to "wire", since a ground wire is also required.  However, I can see this is confusing due data signals going both directions and other control signals that can be part of RS-232.  I removed the reference to "single signal".

Comment: @Chris: I added a section on "line driver" to contrast with just "driver".

Answer (score 3):

A UART is a digital logic circuit and uses digital logic levels for input and output. Depending on the logic chips your UART is in, this logic standard can be 5 V, 3.3 V, 1.8 V or something else.

The UART output pins have relatively weak output current drive. The input pins have almost no signal conditioning and no protection against strong transients. Although they can do it, they're not intended for driving signals up cables or over distances more than a couple of feet.

In practice, the RS232 interface means three things: a communications protocol, a standard for signalling and a set of pins making up a communications interface. For decades, the hardware that implements the communications protocol has been a UART. The full set of pins for communications was intended to control a modem. So even if they exist in the modern RS232 ports you'll come across, most of those aren't used, usually just the Transmit Data (TXD) and Receive Data (RXD) signals plus Signal Ground (GND).

So the main thing that RS232 drivers and receivers will add to your UART is the signalling standard.

A typical RS232 driver uses higher drive currents and higher voltages than the logic standards and bipolar signalling: logic 0 is 3..15 V; logic 1 is -3..-15 V. These carry much better over distance than a TTL. The typical RS232 input buffer has protection against ESD plus some rejection of stronger transients through the low resistance load the inputs present (in the order of 2 K to GND). They will communicate over hundreds of feet of cable, with distance traded off against speed. Example data for this is readily available on the internet.

So you have to consider your application and how electrically noisy your communications path is when you select between the two.

Answer (score 2):

The RS232 driver is designed to be a buffer that can allow the signals to propagate over a set of wires between two devices. The voltage levels put out at the transmit end are relatively higher than the typical UART output and are also bipolar. The RS232 receiver part is designed to be able to detect the mark and space conditions of a received signal of relatively low amplitude. This scheme allows for significant attenuation of the signalling over the wires and still allow communications to take place. The bipolar nature of the signal actually is a benefit to help being able to more easily detect the received signal even if there is some ground level shift between the two pieces of equipment.

Also be aware that the signal level definitions of your 3.3V UART are not likely to be optimum for sending the signalling over a cable between separate pieces of equipment. Concerns here would be related to the UART driver output impedance, voltage levels for high and low and signal rise and fall times. The UART receiver input thresholds and any possible hysteresis would be considerations as well.

UART to UART connections on a single board or even between two boards inside of a piece of equipment are quite common. It saves BOM cost for situations where the drivers and receivers for RS232 signalling levels are not needed.

Standard RS232 drivers and receivers are logically inverting relative to the mark and space voltage levels of the UART I/O pins. This is just how the original definition played out. So if you connect UART to UART without the driver and receiver parts the signalling levels on the wires will be the opposite levels of voltage than what an actual RS232 communications link would be.